# R package - Transferring environment from imported package

Tags: r, package, environment, cran, circos

Assume an R package (*myPackage*) that imports the R package [RCircos](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCircos/index.html) via the DESCRIPTION file and the NAMESPACE file.

```
$ cat DESCRIPTION
Package: myPackage
Imports: RCircos (>= 1.2.0)
...

$ cat NAMESPACE
import(RCircos)
...
```

One of the perks of *RCircos* is that it defines a custom environment (called *RCircos.Env*) and reads/writes variables to this environment from various of its functions. For example, function [RCircos.Initialize.Plot.Parameters](https://rdrr.io/cran/RCircos/src/R/RCircosMain.R) reads and writes to this environment.

```
...
RCircosEnvironment <- NULL;
RCircosEnvironment <- get("RCircos.Env", envir = globalenv());
RCircosEnvironment[["RCircos.PlotPar"]] <- plot.param;
```

(This peculiar behavior has also been recognized by other R packages; see, for example, lines 247-249 of [this](https://github.com/stianlagstad/chimeraviz/blob/master/R/plot_circle.R) package).

Unfortunately, it seems that the environment *RCircos.Env* is not recognized out of the box in *myPackage* when I simply import *RCircos* via the DESCRIPTION file and the NAMESPACE file.

So what can be done?

There seem to be two options of making the environment *RCircos.Env* accessible to functions like `RCircos.Initialize.Plot.Parameters`. However, both of these options cause the CRAN check (`R CMD check myPackage --as-cran`) to issue WARNINGs or NOTEs during the mandatory evaluation of *myPackage* prior to the submission to CRAN, thus preventing its acceptance on CRAN.

**Option 1**: I include the following line directly prior to the function demanding the object:

```
# my code here #
assign("RCircos.Env", RCircos::RCircos.Env, .GlobalEnv)
RCircos.Set.Core.Components(...)
# my code here #
```

However, the CRAN check highlights this line with a NOTE, thus preventing the acceptance of *myPackage* on CRAN.

```
* checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
Found the following assignments to the global environment:
File ‘PACViR/R/visualizeWithRCircos.R’:
  assign("RCircos.Env", RCircos::RCircos.Env, .GlobalEnv)
```

**Option 2**: I load the entire *RCircos* library prior to the function demanding the object:

```
# my code here #
library(RCircos)
RCircos.Set.Core.Components(...)
# my code here #
```

However, the CRAN check highlights this option with a WARNING, again preventing the acceptance of *myPackage* on CRAN.

```
* checking dependencies in R code ... WARNING
'library' or 'require' call not declared from: ‘RCircos’
'library' or 'require' call to ‘RCircos’ in package code.
  Please use :: or requireNamespace() instead.
  See section 'Suggested packages' in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.
```

Surely, there must be an easy and CRAN-compatible way of making the environment *RCircos.Env* accessible to functions such as `RCircos.Set.Core.Components` within *myPackage*! Can someone name and explain such a way?

Comment: Have you tried exporting the environment? i.e. `@importFrom RCircos RCircos.Env` then `@export` using {roxygen2}

Comment: How does one normally get the `RCircos.Env` in the global enviroment when using `RCircos` as a user? `XGR` seems to just call functions like `RCircos.Set.Core.Components()`, never assigning anything to the global environment as far as I can see.

Comment: @Axeman @seasmith So, I did a little bit of digging. It seems that environments and their variables are not transferred when you import a package via NAMESPACE. That is why the environment *RCircos.Env* is not recognized in *myPackage*, even though I have `RCircos` as an import for *myPackage* in the DESCRIPTION file. Is that correct?

Comment: You should be able to access `RCircos::RCircos.Env`, and you can re-export it, as seasmith said. [That's e.g. what `dplyr` does with the `%>%` operator from `magrittr`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/utils.r). But that doesn't solve your CRAN issue that you aren't allowed to write to the global environment

Comment: @Axeman Then how did RCircos get accepted to CRAN in the first place? (This seems to be a chicken/egg problem.)

Comment: There is no code in RCircos like you have: `assign("RCircos.Env", RCircos::RCircos.Env, .GlobalEnv)`. So I guess the question is why you need to have that `assign`.

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl probably CRAN was less strict when RCircos was first submitted. Regardless, this is very bad behaviour; a package should never meddle with the global environment.

Comment: @Axeman A few minutes ago, I updated my question to better explain the underlying issue (see above). In essence, I need the `assign` or equivalent to have the environment *RCircos.Env* recognized in *myPackage*, because simply importing *RCircos* via the DESCRIPTION file and the NAMESPACE file apparently doesn't transfer the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the normal re-export does not work with environments as it does with functions. But this does work:

```
RCircos.Env <- RCircos::RCircos.Env

#' test
#'
#' @param ... data
#'
#' @export
test_fun <- function(...) {
  RCircos::RCircos.Set.Core.Components(...)
}
```

With `DESCRIPTION`:

```
Package: test
Type: Package
Title: test
Description: This is a description.
Version: 0.1.0
Authors@R: person("Wouter", "van der Bijl",
                  email = "redacted@redacted.com",
                  role = c("aut", "cre"))
Maintainer: Wouter van der Bijl <redacted@redacted.com>
License: GPL-3
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Imports: RCircos
RoxygenNote: 6.1.1
```

And this `NAMESPACE`:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(test_fun)
```

Test with:

```
library(test)
data(UCSC.HG19.Human.CytoBandIdeogram, package = 'RCircos')
test_fun(UCSC.HG19.Human.CytoBandIdeogram)
```

---

Basically, when `RCircos` runs `get("RCircos.Env", envir = globalenv())`, it will traverse up the search path until it finds the `RCircos.Env` from your package instead.

When running R CMD Check I get 0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 notes.

---

Note that this strategy that `RCircos` uses, with an environment that gets looked up by using `get(.., envir = globalenv())` is really unorthodox and generally not a good idea. R functions should generally not have side-effects, such as editing unseen environments. Setting default values etc. is typically done using `options()`. The whole package is probably not something you'd want to emulate, but at least now you can use it as a dependency.

Comment: Wow, I take my hat off to you! Your answer did indeed solve the issue. That being said, I still have to include `export(RCircos.Env)` in `NAMESPACE` (as you had suggested in an earlier version of your post) to make my package work.