# No access to "ldTweedie" function from mgcv when called from within another package

Tags: r, namespaces, mgcv, tweedie

I am using mgcv package within my own package and so far everything worked nicely. However, I tried to introduce Tweedie family objects ("Tweedie()", "tw()") to my package, but I am getting an error when trying to use the latter.

The function is as simple as this (simplified here):

```
#' @importFrom mgcv tw
#'
.FamilyLink <- function(link) {
       familyObject <- tw(link = link)
       return(familyObject)
}
```

and I have this in NAMESPACE file

```
importFrom(mgcv,tw)
```

So after installing the package I call my function (non-exported, it's normally used within other function from my package)

```
fam <- MyPackage:::.FamilyLink("log")
fam$aic(1, 1, NULL, 1, 1)
Error in ldTweedie(y, mu, p = p, phi = scale) : 
  could not find function "ldTweedie"
```

Then I tried adding:

```
importFrom(mgcv,ldTweedie)
importFrom(mgcv,tw)
```

Installed the package and got the same problem. However if I load my package using devtools:

```
devtools::load_all("MyPackage")
fam <- .FamilyLink("log")
fam$aic(1, 1, NULL, 1, 1)
[1] 4.05723
```

everything works fine. So I was wondering am I doing something wrong here or how can I get my package/function to work simply by installing and not having to use load_all()? Thank you

Comment: I am not experienced with [R] packages, so this may be unexperienced question; but I am curious, why don't you simply call .FamilyLink(link="log") instead of .FamilyLink("tw", "log")?

Comment: Thanks for comment. It's typo while I was simplifying the actual code.

Comment: Maybe it is related with environments...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272685/how-to-get-r-script-file-name-when-a-function-in-it-is-called
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815606/determine-path-of-the-executing-script
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html 
E.g. function mgcv::ldTweedie is not visible in myPackage:::.FamilyLink function environment... what about if you make .FamilyLink visible outside package?
Sry just guessing what could be the reason :)

Comment: I tried exporting the function, didn't work.

Comment: I still would think the issue relates with environments. Have you ever dealt with them?

Function tw() is in file "efam.r" of the mgcv package. And it has this command:
env <- new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv). In fact, seems like all functions in this file have this statement.

While functions ldTweedie, Tweedie are in the file "gam.fit3.r", and in this file there is only a single function containing env <- new.env(), and this function is negbin().

Perhaps changing env <- .GlobalEnv could solve the issue. Though don't really know how this can affect the calculations done in the package.

Comment: On second thoughts, env <- .GlobalEnv most probably will not help... env <- parent.frame() probably not as well... Maybe env <- environment() would...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but with the help from here [R package - Transferring environment from imported package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875962/r-package-transferring-environment-from-imported-package) the solution is to re-export ldTweedie function from mgcv.

[`dplyr` re-exporting `%>%`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/utils.r)